# Highlighting only the droppable which is hovered or to which item is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

What I'd like to do is to set border color to blue for `.droparea` element that contains an `.item` element.

Also there is also a hover effect for the `.droparea` which changes the border color to blue.

So if I move the `.item` element to another `.droparea` it should automatically change border color for the current `.droparea` to blue and change the border of previously used `.droparea` to default color (black).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    revert: 'invalid',
    stack: false,
    create: function() {
      $(this).data('position', $(this).position())
    },
    cursor: "pointer",
    start: function() {
      $(this).stop(true, true)
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      $(".droparea").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
  $(".droparea").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).addClass("highlight").find("p");
      snapToMiddle(ui.draggable, $(this));
    }
  });
});

function snapToMiddle(dragger, target) {
  var topMove = target.position().top - dragger.data('position').top + (target.outerHeight(true) - dragger.outerHeight(true)) / 2;
  var leftMove = target.position().left - dragger.data('position').left + (target.outerWidth(true) - dragger.outerWidth(true)) / 2;
  dragger.animate({
    top: topMove,
    left: leftMove
  }, {
    duration: 200,
    easing: 'linear'
  });
}
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.droparea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid transparent
}
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
.droparea:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="droparea">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>


<div class="droparea"></div>
<div class="droparea"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to note here:

- jQuery UI draggable only adjusts the style of an element, It does not alter its position in `DOM`, So the `.item` will always be the child of first draggable, and since you've specified the CSS `:hover`pseudo selector - `.droparea:hover`, You'll always be hovering the first droppable while dragging since you're hovering it's child.
- We can fix this issue by setting `highlight` class on hover using the [hoverClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-hoverClass) option of draggable, but since you're removing the `highlight` during `drag` event, the class set on hover will be immediately removed. So we should not remove the class on drag.
- Finally, You can use jQuery UI's [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) utility method for center aligning the item on drop.

So you can achieve what you're trying to as following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    revert: 'invalid',
    stack: false,
    cursor: "pointer",
  });
  $(".droparea").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    hoverClass: "highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
      $this.addClass("highlight");
      ui.draggable.position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $this,
        using: function(pos) {
          $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.droparea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid transparent
}
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="droparea">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="droparea"></div>
<div class="droparea"></div>
```

---

Also, I've to warn you that jQuery UI and CSS float have a bad history, which is evident if you visit [bugs.jqueryui.com](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/). You're better of using `display:inline-block` for this purpose, you can even avoid speciying margin manually.